# Acts_as_list descending instead of ASC numbering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list

I'm using acts_as_list plugin to sort my to do lists.

```
* [drag] Test 1
* [drag] sadf 2
* [drag] asdf 3
```

However I want the numbering to the DESC instead. So it shows as

```
* [drag] Test 3
* [drag] sadf 2
* [drag] asdf 1
```

How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the `order` in the model:

```
class TodoList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todo_items, :order => "position DESC"
end
```

That should produce:

- asdf 3
- sadf 2
- Test 1

assuming your items are:

```
id name position
1  Test 1
2  sadf 2
3  asdf 3
```

Comment: In my model there as just 'acts_as_list' and I was trying to order it and didn't work. However I modified it in my controller and that did the trick. Thanks.